# Visual references for the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, reference-request, soft-question, visualization

I've seen a lot of excellent visual material (gifs, pictures) here, in topics [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733754/visually-stunning-math-concepts-which-are-easy-to-explain), and I used many of them to understand/explain concepts (particularly gifs showing Riemann sums or fourier series), and now I'm looking for material of this kind for the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Any kind would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem at some point, and I could not find much around. After a bit, I found the following.

- [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14529/visualization-of-riemann-stieltjes-integrals#) you find a mathoverflow question on the very same topic, where you find some explanations and some pictures;
- Also, you should really try to find the article "A Geometric Interpretation of the Riemann-Stieltjes Integral", by Gregory L. Bullock (you find the jstor page of that article in Sahadeo Padhye's answer in the previous link). Actually, if you read it, I am sure you will find everything you need (it is a very nice article).

I hope these references will be helpful.

Comment: have you seen the following paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0110241

Comment: No, but I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Grobler, T. (2019). Visualization of the Riemann–Stieltjes Integral. The College Mathematics Journal, 50(3), 198-209.