# Math Ideas to Think About for Kids and Friends

Tags: recreational-mathematics

What are some math concepts and stories that might make someone interested in mathematics?

What are some math concepts that people can think about easily and find it interesting to think about?

I want to try to get kids that I know to start to think about math in creative and fun ways.

Comment: Start with Martin Gardner's books, especially "Aha! Gotcha!" and "Aha! Insight!". Persi Diaconis once said, "Martin Gardner has turned thousands of children into mathematicians, and has turned thousands of mathematicians into children."

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I appreciate it very much!

Comment: how old are the kids?  that's kinda a critical parameter.  :)  anyway supposedly this guy introduced the Euler characteristic in a 3rd grade classroom: http://jdh.hamkins.org/math-for-eight-year-olds/

Comment: this also has tons of very neat visualizations of many math topics, from very easy to rather advanced: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733754/visually-stunning-math-concepts-which-are-easy-to-explain

Comment: well the "kids" are teenagers. about 14-16 with only some background in algebra