# Explanation of a regular pattern only occuring for prime numbers

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, visualization

Consider [multiplication group tables modulo $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118977/visualized-group-tables-for-mathbbz-and-mathbbz-n-mathbbz) with entries $k_{ij} = (i\cdot j)\ \%\ n$ visualized according to these principles:

- **Colors** are assigned to numbers $0 \leq k \leq n$ from

  - $\color{black}{\textsf{black}}$ for $k=0$ over
  - $\color{red}{\textsf{red}}$ for $k=\lfloor n/4\rfloor$ and
  - $\color{silver}{\textsf{white}}$ for $k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ and
  - $\color{blue}{\textsf{blue}}$ for $k=\lfloor 3n/4\rfloor$ back to
  - $\color{black}{\textsf{black}}$ for $k = n$
- **Sizes** are assigned to numbers $0 \leq k \leq n$ by

  - $\textsf{1.5}$ if $k=\lfloor n/4\rfloor$ or $\lfloor 3n/4\rfloor$
  - $\textsf{1.0}$ otherwise
- **Positions** are shifted by $(n/2,n/2)$ modulo $n$ to bring $(0,0)$ to the center of the table.

Visualized this way, you will occasionally find (for some $n$) highly regular multiplication group tables like these (with $n=12,20,28,44,52,68$):

[image]

My question is:

> **Why do these patterns occur exactly when $n = 4p$ with a prime number $p$?**

---

Find here some examples for $n \neq 4p$, e.g. $n=61, 62, 63, 64$:

[image]

---

Here for some other prime numbers: $n = 4\cdot 31 = 124$ and $n = 4\cdot 37 = 148$:

[image]

---

One may observe that for $n = 4m$ and $x,y = m$ or $x,y = 3m$ the "size 1.5" dots are systematically separated by $0$ (= black) and $n/2$ (= white) dots, i.e. that there are only and exactly $4$ values along these lines.

[image]

---

For the sake of completeness: the multiplication group table modulo $8 = 4\cdot 2$ (which also qualifies, but not so obviously):

[image]

Comment: What do they look like when $n$ is not $4$ times a prime?

Comment: Could you include an example of a not so regular table?

Comment: To me the $n\ne 4p$ examples look just about as regular as the $n=4p$ ones, with the exception of the locations of the "size $1.5$" dots.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: To me, too. My question is just about the "size 1.5" dots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To elaborate a bit on Robert Israels fine answer, first note that:
$$
\begin{align}
xy&\equiv n/4\\
xy&\equiv 3n/4
\end{align}
$$
implies that $n$ must be divisible by $4$. Hence we only have such situations when $n=4q$ for some $q$. This is true whether $q$ is prime or not. So let us consider $n=4q$ a bit further. Then we look at:
$$
\begin{align}
xy&\equiv q\\
xy&\equiv 3q
\end{align}
$$
which can be summarized as:
$$
xy=q(2m+1)
$$
for some $m$. This actually reveals why $n=64=4\cdot 16$ also appears to somewhat work. Here $q=16$ so any solutions to $xy=16(2m+1)$ will work. We have the lines $x,y=\pm2,\pm4,\pm8,\pm16$ with varying density of "size 1.5" points.

When $q$ is prime, the picture becomes simpler since all solutions to $xy=q(2m+1)$ have to lie on one of the four lines $x=\pm q,y=\pm q$.

---

**UPDATE:** Some insights on the general case here. Write $n=4q+t$ for $t\in\{-1,0,1,2\}$. Then we have:
$$
\begin{align}
\lfloor n/4\rfloor &= q+\lfloor t/4\rfloor\\
\lfloor 3n/4\rfloor &= 3q+\lfloor 3t/4\rfloor
\end{align}
$$
where we can make the following table:
$$
\begin{array}{c|r|r|r|r}
t & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
\hline
\lfloor t/4\rfloor & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\lfloor 3t/4\rfloor & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
$$
and so we can cover each $t$-case based on that.

---

**CASE $t=0$**

Let us first reconsider the case $t=0$ so that $n=4q$, which was already covered above.
Then:
$$
xy=q(2\mu+1)
$$
will yield "size 1.5" dots. If $q=ab$ is composite then:
$$
\begin{align}
x&=a\\
y&=b(2\mu+1)
\end{align}
$$
will yield a vertical line of points $2b$ apart that are all of "size 1.5". If on the other hand $q$ is prime, then:
$$
\begin{align}
x&=q\\
y&=2\mu+1
\end{align}
$$
will yield a very visible vertical line of points only $2$ apart.

---

**CASE $t=1$**

Suppose $t=1$. Then $n=4q+1$. For this case, having $xy\equiv\lfloor n/4\rfloor=q$  implies:
$$
\begin{align}
xy &=q+\mu n
\end{align}
$$
Now, since $q,n$ are relatively prime, $\mu$ must be a multiple of $q$ for two such situations to have any shared factor. So assume $\mu=\gamma q$. Then:
$$
xy=(\gamma n+1)q
$$
So if $q=ab$ we have:
$$
\begin{align}
x &= a\\
y &= (\gamma n+1)b
\end{align}
$$
showing that no vertical lines can exist, since the $y$-values must be far more than $n$ units apart. On the other hand, plugging in $\mu=0$ in the $y$-expression above shows why points tend to lie on the hyperbola:
$$
xy=q
$$

---

I think the other cases can be broken down in a similar fashion, so I will stop here.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! May I help with specific visualizations? Where and why are you "still a bit unsure"?

Comment: @HansStricker: Thank you. Well, it is just that the "patternless" cases, ie. no horizontal or vertical lines, behave in a more chaotic-seeming manner regarding the 1.5 dots.

Comment: @HansStricker: If you are able to draw more clear conclusions for those "chaotic" cases where $n\neq 4q$ or to visualize them in order to see different principles at play, please let me know. I think the floor function is what throws in the "chaos" in the first place :o)

Comment: Ah! I didn't suspect the floor function. How would you suggest to get rid of it? Any other suggestions to "draw more clear conclusions" in order to "see different principles at play"? (Thanks anyway for your suggestions.)

Comment: @HansStricker: I would put my money on Robert Israel or the like for deeper insights. I merely took his work and explained some helpful details, I guess :o) I regret my comment about the floor function. The main players are the factorizations themselves. The floor function merely compensates for the unsuccesful division of $n$. Any rounding technique would be equally chaotic, I think.

Comment: @HansStricker: I updated my answer. It has turned into more of a full distinct answer now. I hope it makes sense and sheds some light!

Answer (score 9):

If $n=4p$, then for $xy \equiv p$ or $3p$ mod $n$ you need $p$ to divide $x$ or $y$ but $2$ to divide neither: thus the "size $1.5$" dots are all on the lines $x = p$, $x = 3p$, $y = p$ and $y = 3p$.

Comment: Where and how does the primeness of $p$ come into play?