# In Unit circle, in second quadrant, why is X taken negative?

Tags: trigonometry

Cos theta = base / hypotenuse

Base and hypotenuse are lengths, so they should always be positive.

So why is cos 3π / 4 negative ?

Comment: Draw or get a computer or a graphics calculator to draw the graph of $y=cos x$ between 0 and $2\pi$ radians.

Comment: Always positive is from original definition, but extensions to all angles of a unit circle needs signed values for x and y.

Answer (score 0):

I pinched this from another post, but it may help;

[image: circle trig animation]

I think if you look at this animation and think about it long enough, you'll understand:

- Why circles and right-angle triangles and angles are all related
- Why sine is opposite over hypotenuse and so on
- Why cosine is simply sine but offset by $\pi/2$ radians

Comment: You should link to the post from which you took this diagram; chances are good that the question and/or other answers could be useful to OP. (Also, if you are not the original creator of the diagram, credit should be given.)

Comment: @Blue : It's from a community wiki, and happy to link to the post. It does not add anything more, although its a very long and visually stunning romp through beautiful maths - but not relevant to the question asked here. Link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733754/visually-stunning-math-concepts-which-are-easy-to-explain