# Diagrams that wonderfully summarize some of the basic concept in mathematics

Tags: soft-question, education, big-list, visualization

I'm now reviewing some of the undergraduate and graduate math courses and was delighted to see how easy it is to recall certain concepts from linear algebra or homology using conceptual diagram that summarize various key constructions.

Was wondering what other similar diagrams exist?

---

Diagrams that are both informative but that also provide some visual intuition or clues about the underlying notions. 
Something in the spirit of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733754/visually-stunning-math-concepts-which-are-easy-to-explain) soft question, but with the focus of having a diagram that is a summary of certain concepts.

Like the famous diagrams for:

- The four fundamental spaces (from  Introduction to Linear Algebra, Fourth Edition by Gilbert Strang)

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\quad\quad$  [image]

- Chain complex diagram that visualizes some of the relationship between different groups used to define homology (from [Yingkai Liu blog](https://yk-liu.github.io/topology/Introduction-to-Cohomology.html)):

[image]

---

Hope this can qualify for a nice soft-question and generate list of diagram that can be beneficial for people who want to brush through some of basic math constructions.

Comment: Lambda-cube maybe.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words