# The sum of the first n odd numbers is?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

y1 = 1, y2 = 3,
y3 = 5. That second example illustrates that the first n odd numbers add to n^2.

I don't know how to derive n^2 by this matrix.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733754/visually-stunning-math-concepts-which-are-easy-to-explain/733805?r=SearchResults#733805

Comment: You could work backwards: the inverse of $S$ is clearly the matrix with $1$ on the maindiagonal, and $-1$ on the "diagonal" below. Then is you apply this $S^{-1}$ to the vector $1,4,\dots, k^2, \dots, n^2$ you'll get in the $k$-place $(k+1)^2-k^2=2k+1$.

Comment: Just work with $n\times n$ matrix.