# Name of the concept that you take a problem and transform it into a different scheme of thinking, which somehow magically makes it easier to solve

Tags: definition

There are a few instances where converting some co-ordinates from cartesian to polar co-ordinates makes a problem far easier to solve. Something similar is done to improve computational complexity in the Fast Fourier Transform. We also could solve some problems with algebra, or with geometry, and depending on the problem choose a tool for the job. Maybe analogously in physics, treating things as behaving as waves or particles makes more sense in different scenarios.

> I'd like to know the name of this concept so I can read more about it (and find more examples of it); that you take a problem and transform it into a different scheme of thinking, which somehow magically makes it easier to solve.

Comment: See how a simple perspective of a concept creates results in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733754/visually-stunning-math-concepts-which-are-easy-to-explain)

Comment: One possible concept to look into is what's called a paradigm shift, sometimes used in that way, and sometimes to mean how an entire (scientific) community changes their way of thinking or methods in approaching their subject.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "duality" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(mathematics).

Comment: How about the concept of Heuristic.[Heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic)