# Problems with an interesting visual solution?

Tags: geometry, visualization

I am looking for questions which can be simplified and solved with a visual/geometric proof. For example, solving Buffon's needle problem using a circular needle. Preferably understandable for 16-18 year olds, be it with some effort.
Thanks

Comment: Google "Proofs without words".There is also a very beatiful example in Dana Scott's foreword to [this book on mechanised proofs of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$](https://www.cs.ru.nl/~freek/comparison/comparison.pdf) (in the note added at the end of the foreword).

Comment: Questions of this kind should definitely be allowed on MSE. I suggest you add the reference request tag and say a bit about what references you have looked at.

Comment: You may want to check out the book "Q.E.D.: Beauty in Mathematical Proof"

Comment: @MarkS. Please vote to reopen the question.

Comment: @RobArthan I happen to think it doesn't belong on this site because it won't have a definitive answer.

Comment: See the M.SE question ["Visually stunning math concepts which are easy to explain"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/733754/409) and its $110$ (so far!) answers. A [site search for `beautiful`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=beautiful) currently turns up $4599$ results, although not all refer to the visual sense; additional searches should prove fruitful as well.

Comment: @MarkS: it's essentially a reference request. They never have definitive answers.