What are some relations between the golden number or ratio $\phi$, and $\pi$?
What are some relations between the golden number or ratio $\phi$, and $\pi$?
For example,
by considering this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/744196/ ; by Steve Lewis.
Now taking the point at
$\pi$ and not $1/2$, one can notice that at the half of the hypotenuse of the triangle, it's aproximately $\phi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\approx1.618$


https://web.archive.org/web/20221218055624/https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/devlin_05_07.html

How about $\varphi=2\cos\frac{\pi}{5}$?

@J.G. Haha I was just about to write that!

@J.G. yes I was going to type that. $\cos 18°$ had a somewhat similar quadratic expression to that of $\phi$

OP: Doesn't your diagram merely show that $\varphi$ is roughly half $\pi$?

Lmao we can say $$\phi^2-\phi-1=\sin (π)$$

$\phi$ is algebraic while $\pi$ is transcendental. Good luck constructing one from the other using arithmetic and square roots.

Without constraining the operations allowed the question will be ill posed, since there will be any number of relations involving infinitary operations, e.g., $$\frac{16}{\pi}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
\left((42\phi-6)n+5\phi-3\right)
\frac{((2n-1)!!)^3}{(n!)^3 2^{9n}\phi^{8n}}\text{.}$$

@Gwen Or $\varphi^2-\varphi=\varphi-1/\varphi=\sin\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I've remembered a cool integral relating them.

As @BrianTung correctly points out, your diagram shows nothing but $\varphi \approx \pi/2$, to questionable accuracy. If you want to prove something by geometric means, measuring out numerical approximations of irrational quantities certainly is not the way to go about it. This is not to say that you cannot prove facts involving irrational quantities geometrically, but such proofs make use of other properties of those quantities. Now to the point.
The golden ratio is an algebraic number, namely the positive solution of the quadratic equation
$$
x^2 -x - 1 = 0
$$
while $\pi$ is transcendental, meaning there is no polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb Z$ such that $\pi$ is a root of this polynomial. This means that it is impossible to construct one from the other using elementary arithmetic and radicals, or by a compass and straightedge. However, the following identity holds
$$
e^{i\pi/5} + e^{-i\pi/5} = \varphi
$$
following from two facts: The complex tenth roots of unity form a regular decagon, in which two regular pentagons can be inscribed, and the that the ratio of the side length and the diagonal of such a regular pentagon is precisely $\varphi$.
