Simple yet surprising results like $\arctan (1)+\arctan (2)+\arctan (3)=\pi$
I recently found a fun proof of $\arctan (1)+\arctan (2)+\arctan (3)=\pi$ from this answer

It's an "Aha" moment for me as I realized the proof's simplicity, still I was surprised by the result summing up to $\pi$.
What are some results that are straightforward to understand but have outcomes that are unexpectedly profound or interesting?

Do you want especialy graphical proofs ? If such is the case, see here

Why is arctan(red angle in 2nd picture) $= 1$ true?

Nevermind I see it. The two green segments in 2nd picture have the same length and are perpendicular [the slope of one is $2$ and the slope of the other is $-1/2$ so they must be orthogonal]. Nice picture.

$$\operatorname{arccot}(1)+\operatorname{arccot}(2)+\operatorname{arccot}(3)=\fracπ2$$

I like the proof that the area of a regular dodecagon whose radius is $1$ m is $3$ m$^2$

Numberphile has a YouTube video on this problem/solution: The Three Square Geometry Problem.

These are very interesting! The regular dodecagon fact just made my day, sorry mods decided to close it. I think these soft questions has a place here, because without pointing them out, I might never notice them. Just like this one about graphical proofs: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733754/visually-stunning-math-concepts-which-are-easy-to-explain
