Mathematical aphorisms: theorems captured in everyday analogies
What are some popular mathematical aphorisms or sayings that capture the intuition behind a theorem?
Statements such as
A drunk man will find his way home, but a drunk bird may get lost forever   help popularize mathematics through everyday analogies that spark curiosity about the underlying concepts.
For contrast, there are many quote non-examples. Although arguably true, they may not refer to a mathematical result:  In mathematics, the art of proposing a question must be held of higher value than solving it - George Cantor
For this question, the statements should also not oversimplify in a way that it would make the corresponding mathematical statement incorrect or too ambiguous.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733754/visually-stunning-math-concepts-that-are-easy-to-explain/734062#734062

I once wrote a paper that might qualify, except for the "popular": it's titled "Stronger players need not win more knockout tournaments". Journal of the American Statistical Association 76 (1981) 950-951: https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.1981.10477747

A drunk man will find his way home, but a drunk bird may get lost forever. (about)
You can't comb a hairy ball flat without creating a cowlick. (about)
A map of a city placed over the same city will always have a point lying directly over its location. (about)
You can always cut a ham sandwich with a single straight slice so that the bread, ham, and cheese are divided equally. (about)(video)
The real number line is not longer than the coastline of Britain. (about)
You can't hear the shape of a drum. (about)

You mean, the coastline of Britain is longer... or at least it has higher Hausdorff dimension.

Feel free to edit! I suspected that one might be problematic.

Say not longer and it is no longer (pun) problematic. Why someone else has to make that edit? Mathematicians should agree.

The response is marked as community wiki, so anyone can contribute
